# Why the timestamp of the message is later than the rosbag time?

Tags: ros

I'm debugging my code with rosbag replay. In my code, I did tf transform like this:

```
tf.transformPose(target_frame, input_pose, output_pose);
```

Sometimes, there's an exception thrown, which read:

```
"Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  
Requested time 1484037737.206813097 
but the latest data is at time 1484037724.492085834, 
when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [map]"
```

I checked in the debugger, and found the time stamp of the message input_pose is later than the rosbag time:

```
p input_pose.stamp_ 
$1  sec = 1484037737, nsec = 206813097
p ros::Time::now()
$2  sec = 1484037724, nsec = 918256570
```

Also, the rosbag play console shows:

```
 [PAUSED]   Bag Time: 1484037724.967132
```

The commands I used to run the rosbag is

```
rosbag play --clock --pause bagfile.bag
```

And the param use_sim_time is already set to true:

```
$rosparam get use_sim_time
true
```

Could anyone please help with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some tf source publishing at a lower rate. You can debug it looking at `tf_monitor` or `view_frames`.

Also, are you waiting for the transform to be ready before doing the `transformPose` (by using `waitForTransform()`)?

Comment: Thanks, It turns out to be I'm restarting the rosbag play again but the debugging process is not restarted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be I'm restarting the `rosbag play` again but the debugging process is not restarted.